# Rails: rake task change column values in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, rake-task

I have a column name "password" on my db some password has exclamation point(!) character how can i change the  exclamation mark (`!`) character with dollar sign (`$`) using rake task?

This is my code so far:

```
namespace :update_db do
  desc "Change ! Character to $"
    User.where(password: '!').each do |t|
      t.password 
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Are you saving passwords in plain text?

Comment: if not you cannot fire a query over password column to change the `!` to `$` in password because the password is encrypted and saved

Comment: I think also better to add migration in your app and validate field in future instead of creating a rake task. This will work in all environments and you'll sure that you haven't `!` anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
namespace :update_db do
  desc "Change ! Character to $"
    User.where('password LIKE ?', "%!%").find_each do |t|
      t.update(password: t.password.gsub('!', '$'))
    end
  end
end
```

The above solution will fire one query for condition and one query per each updated user.

If you have a lot of users, you can go with single query for update part (using `REGEXP_REPLACE`):

```
User.update_all("password = REGEXP_REPLACE(password, '!', '&', 'g')")
```

P.S. Storing passwords as plain text is not the best idea. [In fact, it's very bad idea](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/120540/why-shouldnt-i-store-passwords-in-plaintext).